# Can Cleric attempt to turn undead instead of usual attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, opportunity-attack

Turning undead is a supernatural ability that a character can perform as a standard action. It does not provoke attacks of opportunity. You must present your holy symbol to turn undead. Turning is considered an attack.

Does it mean, that it can be used instead of usual attack of opportunity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Nope.

A Cleric can not Turn Undead in place of performing an Attack of Opportunity.

Take note of what an AoO actually allows:

> **Making an Attack of Opportunity**
>
> An attack of opportunity is a single melee attack

Particularly, note that no where in [the AoO description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/attacksOfOpportunity.htm) does it allow the character to take a standard action, which is what is needed to perform [Turn Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead).

> Turning undead is a supernatural ability that a character can perform as a standard action.

Even if Turn Undead is "considered an attack", it is still a Supernatural Ability that requires a standard action, not a "melee attack" as specified by the AoO description.

This still doesn't mean AoOs are *entirely* restricted to boring old roll-to-hit-and-damage actions. You can perform maneuvers like [Tripping](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#trip), which are explicitly melee attacks and do not specifically require a standard action to perform.